# Clear form field in jQuery after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

After submission comments, my comment form slides up and hides. I'm using this code, which works:

```
$("#pm-post-form").slideUp("normal", function(){
    $("#mycommentspan").html(g.html).show();
    if (g.preview == true) {
        $("#be_the_first").hide();
        $("#preview_comment").html(g.preview_html).fadeIn(700)
    }
})
```

But I don't want hide it anymore, so users can place others comments.

I tried this code without success:

```
$("#pm-post-form").val("", function(){
    $("#mycommentspan").html(g.html).show();
    if (g.preview == true) {
        $("#be_the_first").hide();
        $("#preview_comment").html(g.preview_html).fadeIn(700)
    }
})
```

I used `val("")` to clear form field content after comment submission, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) only accepts one argument... a value or a function...not both. Also if that selector is the actual form just reset the form (easily researched how). Provide sample html

Comment: Thanks charlietfl for your answer. I will try to reset the form with reset().

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this solution that works.

```
$("#mycommentspan").html(g.html).show();
if (g.preview == true) {
   $("#be_the_first").hide();
   $("#preview_comment").html(g.preview_html).fadeIn(700); // comment placed
   $("#c_comment_txt").val("") // textarea where use place comment, that after submission is cleared
 }
```

After submission, user can place new comment without refresh page.